# C# FireStore, get values from a document

Tags: c#, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get the values inside of a document in FireStore, so I did this.

```
Task<QuerySnapshot> docRef = db.Collection("Logs").GetSnapshotAsync();
foreach (DocumentSnapshot doc in await docRef){
   DocumentSnapshot log = await db.Collection("Logs").Document(doc.Id).GetSnapshotAsync();
   Console.WriteLine(log); // How to get the data in log?
}
```

Thing is that I don't know how to get the Data in log. I tried `log["infoLog"]["name"]` but it doesn't work.

As you can see, the data contains a Map (infoLog) and inside of that, different strings, integers etc..

What would be the right way? Thanks!

### Updated

Tried this

```
        Task<QuerySnapshot> docRef = db.Collection("Logs").GetSnapshotAsync();
            foreach (DocumentSnapshot doc in await docRef)
            {
                DocumentSnapshot log = await db.Collection("Logs").Document(doc.Id).GetSnapshotAsync();

                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in log.ToDictionary())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);

                }
            }
```

But the data didn't come in order. (Because asynchronous I assume)

Comment: Is your issue now on how to get the data in order?

Comment: I just solved it ordering it alphabetically the thing is, is there any way of getting the data order without insert the values into a list and order the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the documents already ordered from the Firestore side by using the `.OrderBy("FIELD_NAME")` or `OrderByDescending("FIELD_NAME")` functions when querying for the data as mentioned in the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data). This way you will get them already ordered so you won't need to order them in client side.

```
Task<QuerySnapshot> docRef = db.Collection("Logs").OrderBy("FIELD_NAME").GetSnapshotAsync();
    foreach (DocumentSnapshot doc in await docRef)
    {
        DocumentSnapshot log = await db.Collection("Logs").Document(doc.Id).GetSnapshotAsync();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in log.ToDictionary())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
        }
    }
```

Just need to replace `FIELD_NAME` with the name of the field you want to order by. In case you want to order by more than one field it can be done as well just by using `OrderBy()` multiple times.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, thanks a lot! :)